# Getting Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded while adding array of objects in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is how my mongoose model is for Question.
And I have updated schema with array of testcases as shown in code.

```
const TestCaseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  input: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  expectedOutput: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
const QuestionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    max: 110,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  difficulty: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  createdat: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  testcases: [TestCaseSchema],
});
```

This is the payload I am sending in api request

```
const payload = {
...,
testcases:[
{
 input:'1 2 3 4',
 expectedOutput:'2 3 4 5'
},
{
 input:'1 2 3 4',
 expectedOutput:'2 3 4 5'
}
]
}
```

The question gets added in mongodb with testcases
[image]

But on frontend when I fetch the list of question it is showing
[image]

My frontend code looks like this

```
const ProblemsTable = ({ data }) => {
const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  });
}
<table className="w-9/12 text-left text-sm text-gray-500">
        <thead className="border-b bg-slate-50 text-xs uppercase text-gray-700">
          {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                <th className="px-6 py-3" key={header.id}>
                  {header.isPlaceholder
                    ? null
                    : flexRender(
                        header.column.columnDef.header,
                        header.getContext(),
                      )}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
            <tr className=" odd:bg-white even:bg-slate-100" key={row.id}>
              {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                <td
                  className="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900"
                  key={cell.id}
                >
                  {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I have fetch my data in server component and passed as prop to this component above then mapping over it in table

Comment: Can you post your front-end code then? Are you looping through results. This sounds like a recursive issue in your code.

Comment: You have added your front-end axios post request but you said "*But on frontend when I fetch the list of question it is showing*" the error. Where is that code? You already said the data gets added to mongodb. Post the code that fetches your list.

Comment: @jQueeny Yeah sorry check now